# replace any html tag to input using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to replace html tags to input with javascript
If the tag is pressed it turns to input

Example:

```
<a href="#">text</a>
```

replace to:

```
<input value="text" />
```

or:

```
<h2 href="#">text</h2>
```

replace to:

```
<input value="text" />
```

This is the code :

```js
/**
  We're defining the event on the `body` element, 
  because we know the `body` is not going away.
  Second argument makes sure the callback only fires when 
  the `click` event happens only on elements marked as `data-editable`
*/
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function(){
  
  var $el = $(this);
              
  var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
  $el.replaceWith( $input );
  
  var save = function(){
    var $p = $('<p data-editable />').text( $input.val() );
    $input.replaceWith( $p );
  };
  
  /**
    We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p data-editable>First Element</p>
  
 <a data-editable class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Second Element</a>
<p>Not editable</p>
```

The problem is: my classes deleted and also not be a tag that has been created 'p' and not "a" or "h2" or whatever

Comment: I think it would be just as easy in vanilla js

Comment: What is the behavior that you trying to achieve? because you can toggle the data-editable attribute

Comment: I want to create a script to do:
If the user presses the text, the text turns to 'input' @Cuzi

Comment: you could `detach()` the element from the DOM intact, and put the `input` in its place. Then re-attach it afterwards, simply changing the text. That way, all the classes, events etc etc of the element should be preserved. https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: I want to do this programmatically ,, because the number of tags that may be too many change @ADyson [link](http://imgur.com/a/pTA3a)

Comment: what is un-programmatic about my suggestion???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly what you are after, check this out

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/evjXZO?editors=1010)

Code:

```
$("body").on("click","[data-editable]", function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  var $input = $("<input/>").val($el.text()).addClass($el.attr('class')).data("tagName", this.outerHTML);
  $el.replaceWith($input);
  console.log($input.data()["tagName"]);
   var save = function(){
    var $p = $($input.data()["tagName"]).text( $input.val() ).addClass($input.attr("class"));
    $input.replaceWith( $p );
  };

  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
})
```

I've just saved the clicked elements classes and html so when we recreate it it comes out as the previous element instead of a static p tag.

Comment: what about preserving other aspects, e.g. events, other attributes, jQuery data, etc etc which might be associated with an element?

Comment: This just saves what he asked for it's probably pretty bad if we wanted to save events and other stuff, so it's basically just a 'hacky' answer to his question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to make the same tag that it was right?

if understood well that will work:

```js
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function(){
  
  var $el = $(this);
              
  var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
  $el.replaceWith( $input );
  $input.focus();
  var save = function(){
    $el.text($input.val());
    $input.replaceWith( $el );
  };
  
  $input.one('blur', save);
  
});
```

```css
.how { color: red}
.green { color: lime}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="how" data-editable>First Element</p>
  
 
<a href="#" data-editable>Second Element</a>
<h2 class="green" data-editable>Second Element</h2>

<p>Not editable</p>
```